# Django Rest Framework Many to Many field data from frontend

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

models.py

```
class PostCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    content = models.TextField()
    post_categories = models.ManyToManyField(PostCategory, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

serializers.py

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        exclude = []
        
    def create(self, validated_data):
        # Retrieve the currently logged-in user
        user = self.context['request'].user
        
        # Add the author user to the validated data
        validated_data['user'] = user

        # Create and return the Post instance
        post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return post
```

views.py

```
class PostCreateView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            serializer = PostSerializer(data = request.data, context={'request': request})
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Passing Data via POST Method from Frontend

```
FormData(3) { title → "Title 1", content → "Content 1", post_categories → "web framework,javascript"}
```

I am using Django REST Framework and trying to implement many to many relationship. I am sending data from frontend to drf backend. Now the error I am facing is:

> post_categories [ "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str." ]

Which is obvious. I believe the error is correct but I don't know how to fix it. I also think once I fix this I will face another error:

> *Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use post_categories.set() instead.*

So I also want to know how can I fix this as well. Please help.

Comment: You need a separate Serializer for the M2M related Model and need to add a Field to the Parent Model where you give the Child Serializer.
The Doku has an example. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

Comment: @Armin I read the documentation but i couldn't figure out How Nested Serializer will help in solving above issue. I need to figure out when post_categories data comes from frontend to backend which is string i need to handle this data in a manner so it will insert into the respected table. The table which connects PostCategory and Post model.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering, "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str.", is because you're sending a string representation of the post categories ("web framework,javascript") instead of primary key values of the categories when creating a Post instance. You need to modify the way you send the data from the frontend to include the primary keys of the selected categories.

To fix this issue, you can make the following changes:

**Frontend**:

When sending data from the frontend, you should send an array of primary keys (PK) representing the selected categories instead of a string

```
{
  "title": "Title 1",
  "content": "Content 1",
  "post_categories": [1, 2]  // Replace 1 and 2 with the actual PKs of selected categories
}
```

DRF Serializer:

Update your PostSerializer to accept a list of primary keys for the post_categories field:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    post_categories = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=PostCategory.objects.all())  # Add this line

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        exclude = []

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # Retrieve the currently logged-in user
        user = self.context['request'].user

        # Add the author user to the validated data
        validated_data['user'] = user

        # Create and return the Post instance
        post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return post
```

The serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=PostCategory.objects.all()) line allows you to accept an array of primary keys for the post_categories field.

With these changes, your DRF view should be able to accept the data from the frontend correctly, and you won't encounter the "Incorrect type" error. Additionally, when saving the Post instance, the many-to-many relationship with post_categories will be established correctly without direct assignment.

Comment: Thanks It helped to get the idea but I used post_categories = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, queryset=PostCategory.objects.all()) and while passing post_categories data from frontend i looped through the post_categories as i was using FormData(). I also omitted the create() method which is inside PostSerializer and added loggedin user directly to request data. Now everything working fine